# Why not able to connect to mLab from Vapor + MongoKitten?

Tags: mongodb, vapor, mongokitten

Try to connect to `mLab` with credentials, but I get this error:

```
fatal error: Error raised at top level: MongoKitten.AuthenticationError.incorrectCredentials: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-900.0.65/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 187
```

my code:

```
let server = try Server("mongodb://xxx:xxx@ds155424.mlab.com:55424")
let database = server["db1"]
let document: Document = ["_id":"asdf"]
try database["full"].append(document)
```

Comment: I believe you should specify DB name in the connection string: let server = try Server("mongodb://xxx:xxx@ds155424.mlab.com:55424/db1")

Comment: Thanks man, you are right, saved my day :)

Comment: Cool, i'm glad I could help you! :) I have no idea why they have it like that, I was struggling with this myself a while ago :)